# Advice on two column php design

Tags: php

I am working on a two-column web page. My goal was to use left side as navigation while right side as main content. It should be like GMail interface:- Right side content changes after options are chosen on the left side.

My current implementation is:

1) Left options generate post request of the same page:

i.e.

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="samepage.php?op=profile>Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="samepage.php?op=chgpwd>Change Password</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2) Then try to parse different ops and generate corresponding content on right side.

```
 if(isset($_GET['op']) && $_GET['op']=='profile') {
 }
 else if(isset($_GET['op']) && $_GET['op']=='chgpwd') {
 }
```

I am not sure this is the correct way. Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

The method you describe IS one way to do it, however if javascript has the possibility of being used may I suggest you give that a try instead.

With JQuery you can make a post OR get request and update dynamically. This way you will cut down on the amount of markup you actually need in your main page (which is always a good thing when you need to make changes)

For example, if you turned

```
<li><a href="samepage.php?op=profile">Profile</a></li>
```

**INTO**

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadContent("profile")">Profile</a></li>
```

This way you can then abstract your actual requests to another page, which makes things much easier, after you grab all the content returned from your loadContent JS function you can then replace the contents of a wrapper div with what was returned.

For example, assume your page has a barebones structure like this...

```
<div id="left-column">
    <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="samepage.php?op=profile>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="samepage.php?op=chgpwd>Change Password</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="right-column">
    <div id="right-column-wrap">
       <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOUR CONTENT WILL BE LOADED IN VIA AJAX -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can throw in your content like this using jQuery...

$("#right-column-wrap").html(content);